# Tigervnc connection refused when using IP address, and accepted with 127.0.0.1

Tags: firewall, iptables, ubuntu-18.04, tigervnc

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I performed an apt get tigervnc-standalone-server adn tigervnc-common.  I am using an xstartup from another host that is running the same setup.  When I attempt to connect to the box with the tigervnc client, I get a connection refused 61 message.  If go directly on the box and attempt to vncviewer 10.207.0.201:5901 I also get a connection refused message, BUT if I do a vncviewer 127.0.0.1:5901, I can connect.   Here is some back ground information.

```
richmaes@portal01:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-07 17:33 PST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
5901/tcp open  vnc-1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

AND then interestingly enough (my eyes pop out of my head) because 5901 is there if I use the home address but not if I use its static address.

```
richmaes@portal01:~$ nmap 10.207.0.102

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-07 17:42 PST
Nmap scan report for portal01 (10.207.0.102)
Host is up (0.000051s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds

And I confirm that I am really know what my local IP is.

```
richmaes@portal01:~$ ifconfig -a
 enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
 inet 10.207.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.207.0.255
        inet6 fe80::56bf:64ff:fe63:43d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:bf:64:63:43:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4295  bytes 3015163 (3.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1526  bytes 150636 (150.6 KB) 
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xef180000-ef1a0000
```

vncserver is listening on port 5901 according to nmap relative to home address only.  I have checked that there are not rules in iptables or ufw.  What is happening here?

```
richmaes@portal01:~$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And the Firewall

```
richmaes@portal01:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 4):

Douugh!

the configuration file /etc/vnc.conf needed a

$localhost = "no";

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Nice catch!

Comment: If you don't want to touch your system-wide `/etc/vnc.conf` file, you can also put the option in `~/.vnc/vnc.conf`

Answer (score 3):

You can also set it on the command line:

```
vncserver ... -localhost no
```